# What is the offical way to tell Microsoft to fix bugs in Tab Common Control

Tags: windows, desktop, common-controls

There are obviously some bugs in Tab control of Common Controls 6

Here is my testing environment showing Tabs in often used way:

[image]

But when I switch to bottom aligned tabs, I get wrong aligned text here.

[image]

When I switch to left aligned view, it becomes more ugly. The underlined mnemonic char, represented with an ampersand in string and correctly interpreted is wildly shown at the end of the tab text and the tab is incorrectly dimensioned. The background colors of the tabs are not themed.

[image]

How can I tell Microsoft in an official way about the bugs?

Comment: @MartinSmith This is about the comctl32 version, not Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1):

CC6 tab control dropped support for everything except tabs on top. Sad but true.

> [This style is not supported if you use ComCtl32.dll version 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-control-styles).